# Reducing the cost of multiplications in numbers

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-calculus, multilinear-algebra

I want to reduce the cost of number multiplication in the Matrix Multiplication. Is the multiplication of a number by $10^n$ or $2^n$ enforces a surplus cost in computer operations or it is just adding zeros at the end of the numbers? If there is not so cost, then an $O(n^2)$ algorithm for MM is available.

Comment: It depends on how you represent your numbers. For ieee binary floating point numbers, multiply by $10^n$ is likely more expensive than by $2^n$. The first case definitely needs rounding. I am not sure if modern CPU implements multiplying by 2 powers differently, because fp operations have became really really fast.

Comment: Thanks, I need a complete answer to the question. Is multiplying by powers of 10, just moving fp on the numbers or no?

Comment: Is the process of multiplying by the powers of the base number (2 or 10) depending the system, like the other multiplications which are interpreted as continuous sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume the standard IEEE binary floating point representation, that is a positive (machine) number is given by
$$ x = 2^n \left( 1 + \sum_{i=1}^m x_i 2^{-i} \right) $$
for $x_i\in\{0, 1\}$, $n\in\mathbb Z$ with $|n| \le N$, and some fixed $m, N\in\mathbb N$.
Then, $x$ is represented by $(x_1,\dotsc, x_m, n)$.

Multiplying $x$ by a 2-power, say $2^p$, results in a signed addition of $n$ and $p$ (with possible over-/underflow). So it is surely not just "moving numbers". Multiplying $x$ by a 10-power results in a full floating multiplication.

I am not sure if any CPU checks for 2-powers and exploits that. Multiplication with numbers of higher precision is more expensive. But, it is always constant given fixed precision.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So in the standard IEEE multiplying by 2-powers does not need the rounding.

Comment: @Danial if there are no under-/overflows, there is  no rounding.